# In Ranorex how to handle popup

Tags: c#, forms, popup, ranorex

In ranorex I have quick question about using conditional statement, or any suggestion to handle a cash drawer popup. Whenever I launch our application there will be a login screen but not every time so what do I do to handle this popup when is there.

These are the two required field that need to be clicked on

```
 Username field:  /form[@title='Windows Security']/?/?/element[@instance='0']/text[@class='Edit']
 Password field:    /form[@title='Windows Security']/?/?/element[@instance='1']/text[@class='Edit']

/form[@title='Windows Security']/?/?/element[@instance='2']/button[@text='OK']
```

How should I handle this? Using if then else statement? If so how do I do this.

Also after I log in there will be cash drawer initialization popup, this is one time for a whole day.

```
/dom[@domain='crs.pre.kofile.com']//input[#'cashdrawerinitialize-btn']
```

this is the button I need to click when this popup appears. Please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your login popup I'd suggest using either optional actions within the Ranorex action table as described in the [Ranorex Online User Guide](https://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/lesson-5-ranorex-recorder/additional-editing-options.html) or using a [User code action](https://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/lesson-7-code-modules.html) that checks if the item exists.

If you decide to  use the User code approach, you can use the following lines

```
if(repo.App.Form.UsernameInfo.Exists(duration))
{
    //Do your steps here
}
else
{
    //What to do, when the first popup is not here?
}
```

Please don't forget to use the Info object of your repository items.

For your second popup, you can use the Ranorex Popupwatcher class as described in the Ranorex code examples (Sorry, but I'm not allowed to post more than to links, yet)

Comment: Also I suggest you 1st confirm/validate an element exists what should be there both times (when popup is there and when it isn't) as then you can check for the popup quicker not having to wait the whole duration each time you look for it.

Answer (score 0):

A common problem in UI testing is the appearance of an unexpected dialog – e.g. the Update-Check dialog in KeePass.

To overcome this issue, you can use the PopupWatcher class. Using this class you can add watches for each dialog which might pop up during test execution. In these watches you can specify a RanoreXPath or a Repository item the PopupWatcher should keep watching for, as well as a method which should be triggered or a repository item which should be clicked.

```
void ITestModule.Run()
{
// Create PopupWatcher
PopupWatcher myPopupWatcher = new PopupWatcher();
// Add a Watch using a RanoreXPath and triggering the Method CloseUpdateCheckDialog
myPopupWatcher.Watch("/form[@controlname='UpdateCheckForm']/button[@controlname='m_btnClose']", CloseUpdateCheckDialog);
// Add a Watch using the info object of a button and triggering the Method CloseUpdateCheckDialog
// myPopupWatcher.Watch(repo.UpdateCheckDialog.btCloseInfo, CloseUpdateCheckDialog);
// Add a Watch using the info object of the dialog and the info object of the button to click
// myPopupWatcher.WatchAndClick(repo.UpdateCheckDialog.SelfInfo, repo.UpdateCheckDialog.btCloseInfo);
// Add a Watch using a repository folder object and the info object of the button to click
// myPopupWatcher.WatchAndClick(repo.UpdateCheckDialog, repo.UpdateCheckDialog.btCloseInfo);
// Start PopupWatcher
myPopupWatcher.Start();
}
public static void CloseUpdateCheckDialog(Ranorex.Core.Repository.RepoItemInfo myInfo, Ranorex.Core.Element myElement)
{
myElement.As<ranorex.button>().Click();
}
public static void CloseUpdateCheckDialog(Ranorex.Core.RxPath myPath, Ranorex.Core.Element myElement)
{
myElement.As<ranorex.button>().Click();
}
```

Or like this:

```
var watcher = new PopupWatcher();
//provide there two elements WatchAndClick(RepoItemInfo, RepoItemInfo);
watcher.WatchAndClick(RepoItemInfoFindElement, RepoItemInfoClickElement);
watcher.Start();
//some work
watcher.Stop();
```